# Can I replace values in a table with SpecFlow.Assist?

Tags: cucumber, specflow

I currently have a step to verify a payment

```
Then I have these payments:
| Payment Type | Amount |
| Cash         | 1.20   |
```

I would like to replace the 'Amount' with a variable, such as bill total which would be in the TestContext.

```
Then I have these payments:
| Payment Type | Amount      |
| Cash         | <billTotal> |
```

I've attempted to pre-process the table before creating my set, but I cannot assign to the TableRow value.  Is there a standard way to achieve this?  Is there a different approach I should be taking?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Please let me know the problem with this question.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using something like this before creating my set:

```
public void AdjustTable(Table table)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var key in row.Keys)
            {
                if (row[key] == "<userFirstName>")
                {
                    row[key] = this.testContext.CustomerProfile.Customer.Name.First;
                }
                else if (row[key] == "<userLastName>")
                {
                    row[key] = this.testContext.CustomerProfile.Customer.Name.Last;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Still open to suggestions!!